# Keep getting an error: Procedure or function 'usp_StoredProcName' expects parameter '@inputVal', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a simple stored procedure which expects 1 input parameter and has 2 output parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_StoredProcName]
    @inputVal nvarchar(255),
    @isError bit OUTPUT,
    @errorInfo nvarchar(255) OUTPUT
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @totalRow int = 0;
DECLARE @inputValID uniqueidentifier;

SET @isError = 1;
SET @errorInfo = '';

SELECT @inputValID = [inputValID]
FROM testTable
WHERE inputVal = @inputVal;

IF @inputValID IS NULL
BEGIN
    SET @isError = 0;
    SET @errorInfo = 'inputVal not found';
    RETURN
END
END
```

To execute this parametrized stored procedure, I have used couple of C# methods and they all return this error:

> Procedure or function 'sp_StoredProcName' expects parameter '@inputVal', which was not supplied.

Method 1 (to call parametrized stored procedure):

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myFullConncectionStringToDB))
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_StoredProcName", con))
   {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputVal", "MyParamVal_12345");

      cmd.Parameters["@isError"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
      cmd.Parameters["@errorInfo"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      var isError = cmd.Parameters["@isError"].Value;
      var errInfo = cmd.Parameters["@errorInfo"].Value;
      con.Close();
   }
}
```

Method 2 (to call parametrized stored procedure):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myFullConncectionStringToDB);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_StoredProcName", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter in_parm = new SqlParameter("@inputVal", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
in_parm.Size = 255;
in_parm.Value = "MyParamVal_12345";
in_parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters.Add(in_parm);

SqlParameter out_parm = new SqlParameter("@errorInfo", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
out_parm.Size = 255;
out_parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(out_parm);

SqlParameter out_parm1 = new SqlParameter("@isError", SqlDbType.Bit);
out_parm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(out_parm1);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Both of the above c# methods return the same error:

> Procedure or function 'sp_StoredProcName' expects parameter '@inputVal', which was not supplied.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here in my C# code to execute the stored procedure.

I am clearly passing the parameter value in both of my methods but can't figure out why it keeps displaying this error.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You have inputVal declared as both a parameter and a proc variable ?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: thank you. Yes that's a good pick regarding the sp_ prefix but the actual stored proc doesn't begin with the sp_ prefix. I've written here just for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting @InputVal as an input parameter in the line right after Create Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_StoredProcName]

@inputVal nvarchar(255),
```

and then creating it again further down as a UniqueIdentifier.

```
DECLARE @inputVal uniqueidentifier;
```

That's not valid syntax.  Change one or the other.  If you don't want to take an input parameter (which would eliminate the error you're asking about), delete the first.

Comment: Hi there, 
I have updated my Stored Procedure as there was typo error. 
The @inputVal and other values values are declared separately. I do get the same error about Stored Procedure expecting inputVal parameter. Kindly have a look at my Stored Proc and my 2 C# method calls. Thank you very much.

Comment: OK the Stored Procedure fixed as that was my typo error. I still get the same error though: Procedure or function 'usp_StoredProcName' expects parameter '@inputVal', which was not supplied